# Solspace Freeform Pro: custom name for file upload?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

We have a working form using Solspace Freeform Pro 4.x. Our page lets non-members of the EE site fill in a form and attach 3 items in 3 separate fields:
Company logo
Game under development logo
Screen shot of their game

However, once the form is submitted, when we login and review the pending submissions, only the first form upload field show an attachment. The other two upload fields have no attachments.

We know this is wrong as the email that arrives has all three attachments, and the directory where the logo's are stored, all three items are there.

Presuming this is a bug, but in case at is something we might have overlooked, how might I fix this issue?

Comment: What exact version number of Freeform Pro are you using? To confirm: do you have 3 separate File Upload fields (outputs 1 `type="file"` field each), or 1 File Upload field that can accept up to 3 files (outputs 3 `type="file"` field fields)?

Comment: Well, I thought I had the most recent version of Freeform installed when I hadn't. I upgraded before replying here and it does work now. Apologies. Question can be closed. For what's it's worth to answer your previous question: we have 3 separate File Upload fields.

:(